# How to send an account verification email in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, email

I have a React Native app with an external API written and managed by a client.
I have a 'create account' endpoint in the API. I want to automatically send users a confirmation email when they register, from which they'll click a confirmation link that will complete their registration.
Ideally, I'd send an email from the app and it would contain text that would trigger a callback that called the 'create account' endpoint.

Can anyone advise me on how to approach this?

Comment: I would really find a way to send the email from the backend

Comment: It is not a good practice to send email from client, use your server. But if you really want to there are email service providers that can let you send mail by HTTP request. https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html